# selectionMode range in calendar doesn't work for month - primeNG

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

**component.html**

```
<p-calendar
    view="month"
    [yearNavigator]="true"
    yearRange="2000:2030"
    [(ngModel)]="rangeDates"
    showButtonBar="true"
    [showTransitionOptions]="'0ms'"
    [hideTransitionOptions]="'0ms'"
    placeholder="Select time period"
    selectionMode="range"
    dateFormat="mm/yy">
   <p-header>Header</p-header>
   <p-footer>Footer</p-footer>
</p-calendar>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html'
    })

    export class AppComponent {
        dates: Date[];
        rangeDates: Date[];
    }
```

I am trying to select a month range from calendar in PrimeNg, but it doesn't work I am getting below 
error.

> ERROR TypeError: this.value.getMonth is not a function

[image: TypeError message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your exact code works for me. I tested with Angular 7.2.15 and PrimeNG 7.1.3

I have seen this error when working from a model that has an empty date array for the daterange, but not as a standalone value. You might consider trying to recreate this on Stackblitz, or if working on older versions, update to a new version if possible.

Comment: Hi @TheTiGuR, Thanksyou for your suggestion. I have created project on Stackbliz link and it is working fine but in my actual project i am using "primeicons": "^1.0.0", "primeng": "^7.1.3" and I was getting above error (ERROR TypeError: this.value.getMonth is not a function). After updating Prime version to "primeicons": "^2.0.0", "primeng": "^8.1.1", it is working fine.